# Android: horizontal gap between linear layout

Tags: android, imageview, android-linearlayout

I am new to Android & this excellent Question / answers site..

Currently i am facing a problem with **gap / space between inner linear layouts**.

I have multiple linear layouts nested (linear layout -> scrollview layout -> multiple Linear Layout).

My objective is to display ImageView (with images) sizes to change dynamically based on device screen resolution.

Each inner layout is having ImageView controls. I wrote to resize each ImageView to fit on screen at run time. At design time inner linear layouts are displayed without horizontal gap, but at rum time due to dynamic code they is a gap between linear layouts.

```
Design display
 ____________   ____________
|            | |            |
|            | |            | 
|  ICON - 1  | | ICON - 2   |
|            | |            | 
 ____________   ____________
    NO horizontal space
 ____________   ____________
|            | |            |
|            | |            | 
|  ICON - 3  | | ICON - 4   |
|            | |            | 
 ____________   ____________


Runtime display
 ____________   ____________
|            | |            |
|            | |            | 
|  ICON - 1  | | ICON - 2   |
|            | |            | 
 ____________   ____________
  un wanted horizontal space
 ____________   ____________
|            | |            |
|            | |            | 
|  ICON - 3  | | ICON - 4   |
|            | |            | 
 ____________   ____________
```

main.xml code

```
    <LinearLayout
    android:background="@drawable/llrightborder"
    android:id="@+id/mainlayoutLeft"
    android:layout_width="0dip"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ScrollView android:id="@+id/scrollView1" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical" android:paddingTop="10.0dip" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"  android:layout_marginBottom="2dip">            

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/leftRow1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageicon1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/icon1"
                    android:layout_marginRight="2dip"
                    android:clickable="true" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageicon2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/icon2" 
                    android:layout_marginLeft="2dip"
                    android:clickable="true" />

            </LinearLayout>


            <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/leftRow2" android:layout_gravity="center" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageicon3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/icon3"
                    android:layout_marginRight="2dip"
                    android:clickable="true" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageicon4"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/icon4"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="2dip"
                    android:clickable="true" />
            </LinearLayout>                      


        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

main.java code for displaying image size dynamically

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();

    iHeight = metrics.heightPixels; 
    iWidth = metrics.widthPixels;

    leftLLWidth = (int) ((iWidth * 25) / 100);
    rightLLWidth = (int) (iWidth - leftLLWidth);


    leftLL = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainlayoutLeft);
    rightLL = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainlayoutRight);


    leftLL.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(leftLLWidth, iHeight));
    rightLL.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(rightLLWidth, iHeight));

    //init image buttons
    img_icon1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageicon1);
    img_icon2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageicon2);
    img_icon3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageicon3);
    img_icon4 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageicon4);

    btnWidth = (int) ((leftLLWidth / 2) - 3);
    btnHeight = btnWidth + 60;


    ViewGroup.LayoutParams button_params = img_icon1.getLayoutParams();

    button_params.width = btnWidth;
    button_params.height = btnHeight;

    img_icon1.setLayoutParams(button_params);
    //img_icon1.setOnClickListener(onMainImgClickHandler);


    img_icon2.setLayoutParams(button_params);
    img_icon3.setLayoutParams(button_params);
    img_icon4.setLayoutParams(button_params);
```

Hope this explaines my issue. Thanks in Advance.

Regards
Nayeem

Comment: Do you want to show 4 icons on whole screen??

Answer (score 0):

have you tried changing the gravity to top?

```
android:layout_gravity="top"
```

Comment: In your code try this:

`LinearLayout.LayoutParams params= new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(leftLLWidth, iHeight);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params2= new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(rightLLWidth, iHeight);
params.gravity= Gravity.TOP;
params.topMargin=0;
params2.gravity= Gravity.TOP;
params2.topMargin=0;

leftLL.setLayoutParams(params);
    rightLL.setLayoutParams(params2);`

Comment: thanks Dyna, I tried above mentioned code... insted of reducing space it increased space...:(

Answer (score 0):

In your parent linear layout you have put width

```
android:layout_width="0dip"
```

which is not right

Comment: yes, as layout is displayed dynamic so initially i fixed as 0dip width and with code i am change.